# Is state.dir directory on broker or application side?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

The documentation states:

**state.dir**

The state directory. Kafka Streams persists local states under the state directory. Each application has a subdirectory on its hosting machine that is located under the state directory. The name of the subdirectory is the application ID. The state stores associated with the application are created under this subdirectory.

Is this directory locally on my client application or on Kafka side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `state.dir` directory is on the machine that runs the Kafka Streams application, ie on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

The client side.

When you running the Kafka Streams application with logging level `INFO`, the streams configuration will be printed in console, ie `state.dir = /tmp/kafka-streams`